# It appears that we have not received any data for this cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-marvel

I install `elastic` and `kibana`,and they all installed `marvel` plugin,but when i open the `marvel` tab on `kibana`,the response is `It appears that we have not received any data for this cluster`.

`Kibana` can add `es`'index, and `marvel` created `.marvel-es-2016-02-18` and `.marvel-es-data` index already.

In `kibana` status tab,show `plugin:marvel   Marvel index ready`

I open the chrome debug mode,and find `/api/marvel/v1/clusters` returns `[]`

es version is 2.2.0.

kibana version is 4.4.1.

marvel version is 2.2.0.

Comment: check this thread https://discuss.elastic.co/t/marvell-2-1-1-error-from-get-api-marvel-v1-clusters/37888

Comment: @PandiyanCool,I don't have a js exception.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted all node,and it became ok.